# How to get last id from json response in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I am trying to extract last id  from a json array. Below mentioned is json array

```js
 [
 {
    "userInfo": {
      "email": "jmeter1 @gmail.com",
      "userName": " jmeter1"
    },
    "id": "2e13f399-5b51-13f0-05b2-623c726eaka1"
  },
{
    "userInfo": {
      "email": " jmeter2@gmail.com ",
      "userName": " jmeter2"
    },
    "id": "3e13f399-5b51-13f0-05b2-623c726eaga2"
  },
{
    "userInfo": {
      "email": " jmeter3 @gmail.com ",
      "userName": " jmeter3"
    },
    "id": "4e13f399-5b51-13f0-05b2-623c726eaha3"
  },
{
    "userInfo": {
      "email": " jmeter4 @gmail.com ",
      "userName": " jmeter4"
    },
    "id": "5e13f399-5b51-13f0-05b2-623c726eafa0"
  }
]
```

`
From above json i would like to extract  value ie. id: "5e13f399-5b51-13f0-05b2-623c726eafa0".

Comment: There's no `srcId` in the data, your title says "last" and your text says "first"...?

Answer (score 6):

Use the JSON Extractor and the JSON Path Expression `$[-1].id`
JMeter uses [Jayway's jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and as per the documentation there, `[-1]` on an array will give you the last element. Test it [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/). Select Jayway implementation on the right.

Answer (score 2):

Extract id_matchNr(totalNumber of id by using Regular Expression Extractor)

use this ${__V(id_${id_matchNr})} expression to get the last id

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JSONPath Extractor configuration:

- Destination Variable Name: any name of your choice, i.e. getid
- JSONPath Expression: $..id[0]

Refer extracted value as ${getid} where required.